# How to get html of large div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which has lots of content. And i want to display an alert when content of that div changes(the div is refreshed every 60 sec). I tried $("div#divName").html() but it is not working as the div has a large content. So what an i do?

```
var $container = $("#load-scores");
$container.load("/include/home.php?ust=" + url_site + "&tz=" + tz);
    var s= $("#load-scores").html();
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $container.load("/include/home.php?ust=" + url_site + "&tz=" + tz);
    var p = $('#load-scores').html();
    if(p.is(s))
        alert("changed");
}, refresh_time);
```

PS:
console.log(p) and console.log(s) is returns empty

Comment: share some code,how refreshing works?

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: You can use the jQuery .change() event handler and then issue a popup, show a div anouncing that the a change has been made.

https://api.jquery.com/change/

$("div#divName").html() will only grab the current html or change it if you have something in .html() such as .html("<p> Hello Dolly!</p>")

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery's load() as a function.

```
var $container = $("#load-scores");
$container.load("/include/home.php?ust=" + url_site + "&tz=" + tz, function(){
        alert("Changed");
    });
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $container.load("/include/home.php?ust=" + url_site + "&tz=" + tz, function(){
        alert("Changed");
    });

}, refresh_time);
```